# C++ "Same Letter" code doesn't work properly

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static char sentence[100];

void sameletter(char sentence[100])
{
    int meter=0;
    char letter;
    cout<<"Enter the letter you want to find in this sentence : ";
    cin>>letter;
    for(int i=0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(sentence[i]==letter)
        {
            meter++;
        }
    }
    cout<<letter<<" letter used "<<meter<<" time(s)."<<endl;
}


int main()
{
cout<<"Enter Sentence : ";
cin>>sentence[100];
gets(sentence);
sameletter(sentence);
}
```

This is code i wrote. But for some reason  it never includes the first letter to the end result. For example lets say i write "We love stack overflow" and i wanted how many times this sentence has the letter "w" so i hit w and it only shows : "w letter used 1 many time(s)." instead of 2. other letters like "o" works perfectly so it's only a problem about the first letter :/ can someone help me about it ?

Thanks !

Comment: `cin>>sentence[100];` does not do what you think it does...

Comment: [Never use `gets()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
cin >> sentence[100];
```

will read a single character into the `100`th index of `sentence`, which invokes underfined behavior.

Also, `gets` has been removed from `c++`, and you should no longer use it.

Instead, you should use [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
int main()
{
  std::cout<<"Enter Sentence : ";
  std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
  sameletter(sentence);
}
```

Also, avoid `using namespace std;`, it's bad practice.

There's no reason for `sentence` to be `static`, or global.

Also, you could just use `std::string`, instead of `char` arrays. It will make your life easier. e.g. your loop could be replaced by an algorithm:

```
int meter = std::count_if(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), 
              [=] (unsigned char c) { 
                return std::tolower(c) == std::tolower(letter);
            });
```

Comment: And that char array being static really serves no purpose. In general, avoid declaring static variables, especially when it serves no purpose.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems `static` changes behaviour at global scope. In this usage the variable is bound to that one translation unit, so it does do something. I don't see any point to it being global, though.

Comment: BTW, the searches for letters are case sensitive.  For example, 'W' != 'w'.  One solution is to copy the sentence, then `transform` the sentence to all lower case.